# Custom react-select createable select component and reach-hook-form typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, react-select

I have a custom component that uses react-select. This uses the `Createable Select` and looks something like:

```
import CreatableSelect from "react-select/creatable";
import {
  ActionMeta,
  MultiValue,
  MultiValueGenericProps,
  OptionProps,
  StylesConfig,
  components,
} from "react-select";


type UserOption = {
  value: number;
  label: string;
  logo?: string;
};


type CustomUserInputProps = {
  userOptions: UserOption[];
  onChange: (
    newValue: MultiValue<UserOption>,
    actionMeta: ActionMeta<UserOption>
  ) => void;
  onBlur: ChangeEventHandler;
  value: UserOption[];
  name: string;
}


export function CustomUserInput ({
  userOptions,
  onChange,
  onBlur,
  value,
  name,
  disabled,
  isEdited,
}: CustomUserInputProps ) {
   ...
   return (
         <CreatableSelect
          options={userOptions}
          onChange={onChange}
          placeholder={""}
          isMulti={true}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          value={value}
          name={name}
          components={{
            Option: CustomOption,
            MultiValueLabel: CustomSelectValue,
          }}
          styles={style}
      />
);};
```

Now when I'm trying to use this with react hook form specifically when editing a form I have something like:

```
interface SelectedUser extends UserOption { isFreeText?:boolean };

type MyFormProps = { initialUsers: SelectedUser[] };

const ThisIsMyForm( {initialUsers}: MyFormProps ) => {
 const defaultValues = {
    users: initialUsers,
  };

  ...
  return ( 
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name="users"
      render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value, name } }) => (
      <CustomUserInput 
         userOptions={userOptions}
         onChange={onChange}
         onBlur={onBlur}
         value={value}
         name={name}
       />
     )}
 />
};
```

With this, I have a typescript error on the `onChange` where it says:

```
(event: ChangeEvent<Element> | { value: number; label: string; logo: string; isFreeText: boolean | undefined; }[]) => void' 
is not assignable to type 
'(newValue: MultiValue<UserOption>, actionMeta: ActionMeta<UserOption>) => void
```

I am not sure how do I satisfy react-hook-form's type on `onChange` and react-selects `onChange` for a `CreateableSelect`

Comment: can you put this in codesandbox and share link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass the `onChange` prop, you need to wrap it in another function with the type '(newValue: MultiValue, actionMeta: ActionMeta) => void'. Inside that function, you transform the data to the `react-hook-form` format and then call the `onChange` function with it.

Like this:

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="users"
  render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value, name } }) => (
  <CustomUserInput 
      userOptions={userOptions}
      onChange={(multiValue: MultiValue, actionMeta:ActionMeta)=>{
        // convert the data and call onChange
      }}
      onBlur={onBlur}
      value={value}
      name={name}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is due to a type mismatch between the `onChange` function expected by `react-select`'s `CreatableSelect` and the one expected by `react-hook-form`'s `Controller`. You need to make sure the types match between these two libraries.

In your case, the type for `react-select`'s `onChange` is `(newValue: MultiValue<UserOption>, actionMeta: ActionMeta<UserOption>) => void`, whereas `react-hook-form` expects an `onChange` type of `(data: any) => void` for the `Controller`.

To resolve this, you can create an intermediate `onChange` function that adapts the `react-hook-form` type to match the `react-select` type. Here's how you can do it:

```
import { Controller, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
// Other imports...

interface SelectedUser extends UserOption {
  isFreeText?: boolean;
}

type MyFormProps = { initialUsers: SelectedUser[] };

const ThisIsMyForm = ({ initialUsers }: MyFormProps) => {
  const defaultValues = {
    users: initialUsers,
  };
  
  const { control } = useForm({
    defaultValues,
  });

  const adaptSelectChange = (
    onChange: (data: any) => void,
  ): ((newValue: MultiValue<UserOption>, actionMeta: ActionMeta<UserOption>) => void) => {
    return (newValue, actionMeta) => {
      // Adapt the data to match the react-hook-form's expected format
      const adaptedData = newValue.map(option => ({ value: option.value, label: option.label }));
      onChange(adaptedData);
    };
  };

  return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name="users"
      render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value, name } }) => (
        <CustomUserInput
          userOptions={userOptions}
          onChange={adaptSelectChange(onChange)}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          value={value}
          name={name}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

This code snippet adapts the `onChange` function to match the `react-hook-form` expected format by mapping the selected options to the necessary format.